# A logic statement. "or" in Abstract algebra - groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic

> Let H be the subset of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ consisting of all matrices of the form
>
> $H^* = \left \{ \begin{pmatrix}
> a &-b \\ 
>  b&a 
> \end{pmatrix} : a,b\in\mathbb{R} , a\neq 0 \; \text{or} \; b \neq 0\right\}$
>
> Is (H*, .) a group under multiplication?

I said no because since $b \neq 0$, the identity matrix can't exist. But my prof briefly said "either a **or** b can't be 0, not a **and** b"

Am I right or his wrong?

Comment: Note that your last line is false (and syntactically incorrect). You're not right and he's not wrong. However you are wrong, and he is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He’s right, and you’re wrong. The definition

$$H^* = \left \{ \begin{pmatrix}
a &-b \\ 
 b&a 
\end{pmatrix} : a,b\in\mathbb{R} , a\neq 0 \; \text{or} \; b \neq 0\right\}$$

makes $H^*$ the collection of all $2\times 2$ real matrices such that **at least one** of $a$ and $b$ is non-zero. The identity matrix is such a matrix: for it you have $a\ne 0$.

The condition $$a\ne 0\text{ or }b\ne 0$$ is equivalent to the condition $$(a\ne 0\text{ and }b\ne 0)\text{ or }(a\ne 0)\text{ and }b=0)\text{ or }(a=0\text{ and }b\ne 0)\;;$$ the only case that it excludes is $a=b=0$. In mathematics and logic, **or** is inclusive: ‘$a\text{ or }b$’ is ‘$a\text{ or }b\text{ or both}$’.

Comment: So what is an example of what i mean? That is when $b \neq 0$ ever? How do I say that?

Comment: @jak: If the definition had been $$H^*=\left\{\pmatrix{a&-b\\b&a}:a,b\in\Bbb R,a\neq 0\text{ and }b\neq 0\right\}\;,$$ your objection would have been correct. That definition requires that $a$ and $b$ **both** be non-zero and therefore excludes the identity matrix.

Answer (score 4):

In mathematics the use of the word **or** is inclusive, not exclusive. It is possible that only $b\neq 0$, it is possible that only $a\neq 0$, and it is possible that *both* $a\neq0$ and $b\neq 0$.

It is only impossible that both $a=b=0$.

So the identity matrix is in $H^\ast$, since $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ has the wanted property.